# MySQL, UTF-8 and Emoji characters

Tags: php, mysql, ios, utf-8, emoji

I'm working on an iOS app with a PHP+MySQL backend. The app has a chat section, which needs to support emoji.
My tables are utf8_unicode_ci. If I don't call 'set names utf8' in my scripts, emoji it actually works - whatever is entered in the database, is returned to the clients as it should.

The problem is that this (if I understand it correctly) stores special characters incorrectly in the database, and this breaks string comparing (ie ï is no longer the same as i when comparing strings).

However, if I do call set names utf8, suddenly the emoji characters are inserted as a bunch of questionmarks.

Any suggestions on the proper way of handling this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is wether the db has a diacritical insensitive compare. The other issue is composed characters, ï can be expressed as either one unicode character or two forming a surrogate pair. There are methods to convert a string to a pre-composed or decomposed form: precomposedStringWith* and decomposedStringWith*.

It seems that MySQL supports two forms of unicode ucs2 (that is an older form that was supersede by utf16) which is 16-bits per character and utf8 up to 3 bytes per character. The bad news is that neither form is going to support plane 1 characters which require at 17 bits. (mainly emoji). It looks like MySQL 5.5.3 and up also support utf8mb4, utf16, and utf32 support BMP and supplementary characters (read emoji). See [MySQL Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

Here is some code and results to demonstrate the different unicode byte representations.
Unicode is a 21 bit encoding system.
UTF32 directly represents the code points and clearly demonstrates decomposed surrogate pairs.
UTF8 and UTF16 require one or more bytes to represent a unicode character.

```
NSLog(@"character: %@", @"Å");
NSLog(@"decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF8:  %@", [[@"Å" decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF16: %@", [[@"Å" decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF32: %@", [[@"Å" decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);

NSLog(@"precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF8:  %@", [[@"Å" precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF16: %@", [[@"Å" precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF32: %@", [[@"Å" precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);

NSLog(@"character: %@", @"");
NSLog(@"dataUsingEncoding UTF8:  %@", [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"dataUsingEncoding UTF16: %@", [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"dataUsingEncoding UTF32: %@", [@"" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);
```

// For some surrogate pairs there is no other form

```
NSString *aReverse = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:"\xD8\x3C\xDD\x70\x00" length:4 encoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"character: %@", aReverse);
NSLog(@"dataUsingEncoding UTF8:  %@", [aReverse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"dataUsingEncoding UTF16: %@", [aReverse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding]);
NSLog(@"dataUsingEncoding UTF32: %@", [aReverse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding]);
```

NSLog output:

```
character: Å
decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF8:  <41cc8a>   
decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF16: <0041030a>   
decomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF32: <00000041 0000030a>   

precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF8:  <c385>   
precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF16: <00c5>   
precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping UTF32: <000000c5>   

character: 
dataUsingEncoding UTF8:  <f09f98b1>   
dataUsingEncoding UTF16: <d83dde31>   
dataUsingEncoding UTF32: <0001f631>   

character: 
dataUsingEncoding UTF8:  <f09f85b0>
dataUsingEncoding UTF16: <d83cdd70>
dataUsingEncoding UTF32: <0001f170>
```

Comment: This seems to be really useful information. I can't verify at the moment because I can't upgrade my MySQL at the moment, but I am going to assume you are correct and accept your answer :) Thanks!

Comment: I have an additional question if you don't mind. If I don't need string matching like I described, are there any other downsides to not calling set names utf8? I know the data is inserted incorrectly, but it works when displaying the data in the clients.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know anything about `set names utf8`, it has been years since I wrote code to work with MySQL. Do use Plane 1 code points for testing (emoji are in Plane 1). Also surrogated pairs but they probably only are issues for comparisons. I have added some code and results to the answer to demonstrate the different unicode byte representations.

Comment: Wanted to inform you that I upgraded MySQL and changed my character sets to utf8mb4_unicode_ci - and all is well now. Thank you very much!