# How remove non-ascii from string - c#

Tags: c#, regex, emoji

I want to remove emoji from string, but it doesn't work

```
string str = "Hello world ☀⛿"; 
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

Comment: What is that regex supposed to do? It doesn't look even remotely useful for your purpose.

Comment: I think the solution is blindly taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/28025891/3832970

Comment: Oh, if Jon Skeet suggested that, then it must work. I just tried it with an online regex page that doesn't support that.

Comment: Is the [last one](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E2%9B%BF#title) in the string an emoji char? It is a flag.

Comment: @Andrew It's on product title

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it be good if you test it and share a link, because it's link isn't solve this, you can test

Comment: @asa: I cannot test anything because you have not posted the requirements. What is an emoji for you? What Unicode ranges do you need to cover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I compared several options I found/thought of:

```
string text = "Hello world ☀⛿END";

Console.WriteLine(text);
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, @"\p{Cs}", ""));
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", ""));
Console.WriteLine(text.Where(c => !Char.IsSurrogate(c)).ToArray());
```

And this is the outcome:

```
Hello world ??????END
Hello world ??END
Hello world END
Hello world ??END
```

I am not sure if your input string, after being copied, pasted here, copied again and pasted into Visual Studio suffers some modification in the process, but from what I see, obviously the second option seems to work better.

Do you want to remove all special characters or **only emoji**?

Comment: Regex.Replace(str, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", ""); works and thanks

Comment: However, it does not only match "emojis", it will remove Cyrillic letters and much more.

Comment: Exactly. My guess is that @asa just needs to remove *strange* characters and doesn't expect anything special. Is that right?