# Detecting *all* emojis

Tags: c#, regex, string, char, emoji

Right now I'm using this piece of code :

```
public static bool ContainsEmoji(this string text)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\p{Cs}");
    return rgx.IsMatch(text);
}
```

And it's being somewhat helpful.

Most of them appear to be detected, but some aren't.

Here's a reference list to help : http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

All the smiley faces appear to be fine, but these specific emojis do not get caught by the Regex :

1920    U+2614  ☔   umbrella with rain drops

1921    U+26F1  ⛱   umbrella on ground

1922    U+26A1  ⚡   high voltage

1923    U+2744  ❄   snowflake

On the keyboard these are not close to each other, but in the list they are following each other, so I just assumed that there was a point where it would start not working in the emoji list, and it's not really verifying. From 1905 (weather-like emojis), going down, some are caught in the regex, some aren't. There does not seem to be any rule.

I can't afford to just go full ASCII because I need people to enter characters such as cyrillic, but I can't accept emojis specifically. I have no clue how to go forward from here.

I read the [MSDN docs about surrogates high/low pairs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcwwfbb8(v=vs.110).aspx), but at this stage this is very confusing to me, and I think some push in the right direction would go a long way.

Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: None of those are above U+10000, so they're not represented as surrogate pairs - it's unsurprising that the regex doesn't catch them. (I'm not sure I'd call them emoji as such.)

Comment: All of those are in the "symbol, other" (So) category though, so maybe just use that as another category.

Comment: @musefan I don't know which one I'm missing ; i've randomly tested some in the keyboard as a first try and these were my results.

Comment: Also note that you're not catching "emojis" but surrogate pairs (when encoded UTF16). Your regex will match also some Korean characters, for example. `{Cs}` is equivalent to `{Surrogate}`. AFAIK there isn't an Unicode category for emojis then you have to list each sub-range separately.

Comment: @JonSkeet So I just need to take the first emoji's code and block the complete range?

Comment: @GilSand: oh...ok... it was just that you said `"but these specific emojis do not get caught"`

Comment: No, I would consider whether you want to block everything in the "Symbols, other" category and block that if so. Alternatively, whitelist the categories that you want to *allow*.

Comment: Okay, so this is not a quick dev like I thought it was. I'll need to define all those categories

Comment: @Gil in addition to [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905176/detecting-all-emojis#comment80757157_46905176) also note that there might be combining characters together with "emoji" characters. See for example [Why are emoji characters like ‍‍‍ treated so strangely in Swift strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43618487/why-are-emoji-characters-like-treated-so-strangely-in-swift-strings)

Comment: May be duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023682/how-do-i-remove-emoji-characters-from-a-string

Comment: @tetralobita Look in the comments of the answer of that question you just linked

Comment: I created a [.NET emoji regex gist](https://gist.github.com/stribizhev/54d0193c5c9883757a6e87d18263f790). The pattern should be improved, I will be working on it.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew pattern is longer than I expected!

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You may use the following regex to match all [4702 emoji characters](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html) defined in the [Emoji Keyboard/Display Test Data for UTR #51 (Version: 14.0)](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/14.0/emoji-test.txt) file:

```
var EmojiPattern = @"[#*0-9]\uFE0F?\u20E3|©\uFE0F?|[®\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA]\uFE0F?|[\u231A\u231B]|[\u2328\u23CF]\uFE0F?|[\u23E9-\u23EC]|[\u23ED-\u23EF]\uFE0F?|\u23F0|[\u23F1\u23F2]\uFE0F?|\u23F3|[\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB\u25FC]\uFE0F?|[\u25FD\u25FE]|[\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611]\uFE0F?|[\u2614\u2615]|\u2618\uFE0F?|\u261D(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)?|[\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|[\u2648-\u2653]|[\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E]\uFE0F?|\u267F|\u2692\uFE0F?|\u2693|[\u2694-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0]\uFE0F?|\u26A1|\u26A7\uFE0F?|[\u26AA\u26AB]|[\u26B0\u26B1]\uFE0F?|[\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5]|\u26C8\uFE0F?|\u26CE|[\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3]\uFE0F?|\u26D4|\u26E9\uFE0F?|\u26EA|[\u26F0\u26F1]\uFE0F?|[\u26F2\u26F3]|\u26F4\uFE0F?|\u26F5|[\u26F7\u26F8]\uFE0F?|\u26F9(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uFE0F(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\u26FA\u26FD]|\u2702\uFE0F?|\u2705|[\u2708\u2709]\uFE0F?|[\u270A\u270B](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\u270C\u270D](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)?|\u270F\uFE0F?|[\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721]\uFE0F?|\u2728|[\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747]\uFE0F?|[\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757]|\u2763\uFE0F?|\u2764(?:\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDD25|\uD83E\uDE79)|\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDD25|\uD83E\uDE79))?)?|[\u2795-\u2797]|\u27A1\uFE0F?|[\u27B0\u27BF]|[\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07]\uFE0F?|[\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]|[\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|\uD83C(?:[\uDC04\uDCCF]|[\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F]\uFE0F?|[\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A]|\uDDE6\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF]|\uDDE7\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDE8\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF]|\uDDE9\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF]|\uDDEA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA]|\uDDEB\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7]|\uDDEC\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDED\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA]|\uDDEE\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9]|\uDDEF\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5]|\uDDF0\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDF1\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE]|\uDDF2\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF]|\uDDF3\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF]|\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uDDF5\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uDDF7\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC]|\uDDF8\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF]|\uDDF9\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF]|\uDDFA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDFB\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA]|\uDDFC\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8]|\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uDDFE\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9]|\uDDFF\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC]|\uDE01|\uDE02\uFE0F?|[\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36]|\uDE37\uFE0F?|[\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20]|[\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF2C]\uFE0F?|[\uDF2D-\uDF35]|\uDF36\uFE0F?|[\uDF37-\uDF7C]|\uDF7D\uFE0F?|[\uDF7E-\uDF84]|\uDF85(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDF86-\uDF93]|[\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E\uDF9F]\uFE0F?|[\uDFA0-\uDFC1]|\uDFC2(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDFC3\uDFC4](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDFC5\uDFC6]|\uDFC7(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDFC8\uDFC9]|\uDFCA(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDFCB\uDFCC](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uFE0F(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDFCD\uDFCE]\uFE0F?|[\uDFCF-\uDFD3]|[\uDFD4-\uDFDF]\uFE0F?|[\uDFE0-\uDFF0]|\uDFF3(?:\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDF08)|\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDF08))?)?|\uDFF4(?:\u200D\u2620\uFE0F?|\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62\uDB40(?:\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67|\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74|\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73)\uDB40\uDC7F)?|[\uDFF5\uDFF7]\uFE0F?|[\uDFF8-\uDFFF])|\uD83D(?:[\uDC00-\uDC07]|\uDC08(?:\u200D\u2B1B)?|[\uDC09-\uDC14]|\uDC15(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA)?|[\uDC16-\uDC3A]|\uDC3B(?:\u200D\u2744\uFE0F?)?|[\uDC3C-\uDC3E]|\uDC3F\uFE0F?|\uDC40|\uDC41(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?|\uFE0F(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDC42\uDC43](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC44\uDC45]|[\uDC46-\uDC50](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC51-\uDC65]|[\uDC66\uDC67](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC68(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?|[\uDC68\uDC69]\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?))?|\uDC69(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?[\uDC68\uDC69]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?|\uDC69\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?))?|\uDC6A|[\uDC6B-\uDC6D](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC6E(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDC6F(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDC70\uDC71](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDC72(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC73(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDC74-\uDC76](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC77(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDC78(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC79-\uDC7B]|\uDC7C(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC7D-\uDC80]|[\uDC81\uDC82](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDC83(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC84|\uDC85(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC86\uDC87](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDC88-\uDC8E]|\uDC8F(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC90|\uDC91(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC92-\uDCA9]|\uDCAA(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDCAB-\uDCFC]|\uDCFD\uFE0F?|[\uDCFF-\uDD3D]|[\uDD49\uDD4A]\uFE0F?|[\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67]|[\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73]\uFE0F?|\uDD74(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)?|\uDD75(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uFE0F(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDD76-\uDD79]\uFE0F?|\uDD7A(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D]\uFE0F?|\uDD90(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)?|[\uDD95\uDD96](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDA4|[\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA]\uFE0F?|[\uDDFB-\uDE2D]|\uDE2E(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDCA8)?|[\uDE2F-\uDE34]|\uDE35(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDCAB)?|\uDE36(?:\u200D\uD83C\uDF2B\uFE0F?)?|[\uDE37-\uDE44]|[\uDE45-\uDE47](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDE48-\uDE4A]|\uDE4B(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDE4C(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDE4D\uDE4E](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDE4F(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDE80-\uDEA2]|\uDEA3(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDEA4-\uDEB3]|[\uDEB4-\uDEB6](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDEB7-\uDEBF]|\uDEC0(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDEC1-\uDEC5]|\uDECB\uFE0F?|\uDECC(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDECD-\uDECF]\uFE0F?|[\uDED0-\uDED2\uDED5-\uDED7]|[\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9]\uFE0F?|[\uDEEB\uDEEC]|[\uDEF0\uDEF3]\uFE0F?|[\uDEF4-\uDEFC\uDFE0-\uDFEB])|\uD83E(?:\uDD0C(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD0D\uDD0E]|\uDD0F(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD10-\uDD17]|[\uDD18-\uDD1C](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD1D|[\uDD1E\uDD1F](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD20-\uDD25]|\uDD26(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDD27-\uDD2F]|[\uDD30-\uDD34](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD35(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDD36(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD37-\uDD39](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDD3A|\uDD3C(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDD3D\uDD3E](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDD3F-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD76]|\uDD77(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD78\uDD7A-\uDDB4]|[\uDDB5\uDDB6](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDB7|[\uDDB8\uDDB9](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDDBA|\uDDBB(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDDBC-\uDDCB]|[\uDDCD-\uDDCF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDDD0|\uDDD1(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))|\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])))?))?|[\uDDD2\uDDD3](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDD4(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|\uDDD5(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDDD6-\uDDDD](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?)?|[\uDDDE\uDDDF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDDE0-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE74\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE90-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEB6\uDEC0-\uDEC2\uDED0-\uDED6])";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxJYXs/4) (although the JS option is used, the regex yields the same result in C#.)

The pattern is created dynamically from the list of emojis and contracted using a regex trie, with a couple of post-process steps to shrink the pattern even more.

If you need to check if the whole string is solely composed of emojis, wrap the above pattern with a group, append anchors on both ends, and add `+` (one or more) / `*` (zero or more) quantifier to the group.

```cs
// If the string should contain at least one emoji:
var rx = $@"^(?:{EmojiPattern})+\z";
var rx = $@"^(?:{EmojiPattern})+$";
// Or, to allow empty strings
var rx = $@"^(?:{EmojiPattern})*\z";
var rx = $@"^(?:{EmojiPattern})*$";
```

Here, `^` matches the start of string, `$` matches the end of string (but there may be a final `\n` at the end of string) and `\z` matches the very end of string.

Comment: It would be great if you were able to put the code to generate this on GitHub or somewhere for future Unicode updates.

Comment: @MatthewWalton I used C# and PHP and wanted to merge it all into single language code, but did not succeed. I am now busy with something different, once I manage to combine it all, I will update.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Did you ever release the source of this?

Comment: @MMM You must be mentioning it because of the emoji list update. I still have not found a way to unify the code. I will update the post with the new regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew actually I wasn't even aware that the list had updated, I was just curious ;) Thanks anyways, I'll be looking forward to the new regex!

Comment: Would it be possible to have this regex updated for v13?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no problem!

Comment: @mcont I updated the regex to 13.1 version.

Comment: @mcont Updated to Emoji Version 14.0.

Answer (score 9):

The Unicode Technical Standard #51 defines [a regular expression pattern for detecting Emoji](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/#EBNF_and_Regex) based on the Unicode character properties. It needs translation into your language and RegExp library of choice and relies on Unicode support in those patterns.

```
\p{RI} \p{RI} 
| \p{Emoji} 
  ( \p{EMod} 
  | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
  | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  (\x{200D} \p{Emoji}
    ( \p{EMod} 
    | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
    | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  )*
```

By relying on these character properties it won't be as necessary to maintain a custom database or table of known characters and combinations. Unicode specification updates should trickle down through the provided framework, language, or platform.

I've done this for JavaScript but alas not for C#, still I'm hoping that this answer helps out.

```js
const emoji = new RegExp(
  '(?:' +                                    /*** Proper "Emoji" ***/
    '\\p{RI}\\p{RI}' +                       // Regional indicators like  +  = 
    '|' +
    '\\p{Emoji}' +                           // Emoji character
    '(?:' +                                  // optionally followed…
      '\\p{Emoji_Modifier}' +                //   …with a modifier like skin-tone, hair style, etc…
      '|' +
      '\\u{FE0F}\\u{20E3}?' +                //   …with "visual representation" marker ☂ vs ☂️
      '|' +                                  //         "combining visual keycap" a vs. a⃣
      '[\\u{E0020}-\\u{E007E}]+\\u{E007F}' + //   …with Emoji tag sequences for flags
    ')?' +
    '(?:' +
      '\\u{200D}\\p{Emoji}' +                // …with zero or more ZWJ sequences
      '(?:' +                                //   …each of which might also have modifier
        '\\p{Emoji_Modifier}' +              //      sequences as on the base Emoji above
        '|' +
        '\\u{FE0F}\\u{20E3}?' +
        '|' +
        '[\\u{E0020}-\\u{E007E}]+\\u{E007F}' +
      ')?' +
    ')*' +
  ')',
  'gu'                                       // Global to find all matches and persist `lastIndex` if necessary
);
```

and also as a one-liner with [a regex101 link](https://regex101.com/r/ryE7kc/1)

```js
/(?:\p{RI}\p{RI}|\p{Emoji}(?:\p{Emoji_Modifier}|\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}?|[\u{E0020}-\u{E007E}]+\u{E007F})?(?:\u{200D}\p{Emoji}(?:\p{Emoji_Modifier}|\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}?|[\u{E0020}-\u{E007E}]+\u{E007F})?)*)|[\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}]/gu
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work with C#, because C# doesn't support \p{Emoji} \p{PI} etc..

Answer (score 1):

I've taken Wiktor Stribiżew's idea of generating a regular expression from the Emoji Keyboard/Display Test Data file and implemented it [here](https://github.com/Felk/UnicodeEmojiRegex). An UTF-16 based regular expression that matches exactly the emojis listed in the test file for *UNICODE EMOJI 13.1* looks like this:

```
\uD83D(?:\uDC68(?:\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?)|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68|\uD83D(?:(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\u200D\uD83D)?(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))?|\uDC69(?:\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?)|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83D(?:(?:\uDC69\u200D\uD83D)?(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))?|(?:\uDD75(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)?|\uDC6F)(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDC6E\uDC70\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uDC41(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?)?|\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?)?|\uDE36(?:\u200D\uD83C\uDF2B\uFE0F?)?|\uDC15(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA)?|\uDC3B(?:\u200D\u2744\uFE0F?)?|\uDE2E(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDCA8)?|\uDE35(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDCAB)?|[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66\uDC67\uDC6B-\uDC6D\uDC72\uDC74-\uDC76\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC83\uDC85\uDC8F\uDC91\uDCAA\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDE4C\uDE4F\uDEC0\uDECC](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD74\uDD90]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC08(?:\u200D\u2B1B)?|[\uDC3F\uDCFD\uDD49\uDD4A\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73\uDD74\uDD76-\uDD79\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA\uDECB\uDECD-\uDECF\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEF0\uDEF3]\uFE0F?|[\uDC00-\uDC07\uDC09-\uDC14\uDC16-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3E\uDC40\uDC44\uDC45\uDC51-\uDC65\uDC6A\uDC79-\uDC7B\uDC7D-\uDC80\uDC84\uDC88-\uDC8E\uDC90\uDC92-\uDCA9\uDCAB-\uDCFC\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDDA4\uDDFB-\uDE2D\uDE2F-\uDE34\uDE37-\uDE44\uDE48-\uDE4A\uDE80-\uDEA2\uDEA4-\uDEB3\uDEB7-\uDEBF\uDEC1-\uDEC5\uDED0-\uDED2\uDED5-\uDED7\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF4-\uDEFC\uDFE0-\uDFEB])|\uD83E(?:\uDDD1(?:\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?)|\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|[\uDD26\uDD35\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD4\uDDD6-\uDDDD](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDD3C\uDDDE\uDDDF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDD0C\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD30-\uDD34\uDD36\uDD77\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDBB\uDDD2\uDDD3\uDDD5](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD0D\uDD0E\uDD10-\uDD17\uDD1D\uDD20-\uDD25\uDD27-\uDD2F\uDD3A\uDD3F-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD76\uDD78\uDD7A-\uDDB4\uDDB7\uDDBA\uDDBC-\uDDCB\uDDD0\uDDE0-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE74\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE90-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEB6\uDEC0-\uDEC2\uDED0-\uDED6])|\uD83C(?:\uDFF4(?:\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62\uDB40(?:\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67|\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74|\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73)\uDB40\uDC7F|\u200D\u2620\uFE0F?)?|[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDFCB\uDFCC](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uDFF3(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDF08))?|\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDF08))?|(?:[\uDFCB\uDFCC]\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDE02\uDE37\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF2C\uDF36\uDF7D\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E\uDF9F\uDFCD\uDFCE\uDFD4-\uDFDF\uDFF5\uDFF7])\uFE0F?|[\uDF85\uDFC2\uDFC7](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDE6\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF]|\uDDE7\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDE8\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF]|\uDDE9\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF]|\uDDEA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA]|\uDDEB\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7]|\uDDEC\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDED\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA]|\uDDEE\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9]|\uDDEF\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5]|\uDDF0\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDF1\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE]|\uDDF2\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF]|\uDDF3\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF]|\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uDDF5\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uDDF7\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC]|\uDDF8\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF]|\uDDF9\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF]|\uDDFA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDFB\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA]|\uDDFC\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8]|\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uDDFE\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9]|\uDDFF\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC]|[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDE01\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20\uDF2D-\uDF35\uDF37-\uDF7C\uDF7E-\uDF84\uDF86-\uDF93\uDFA0-\uDFC1\uDFC5\uDFC6\uDFC8\uDFC9\uDFCB\uDFCC\uDFCF-\uDFD3\uDFE0-\uDFF0\uDFF8-\uDFFF])|\u26F9(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u2764(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDD25|\uD83E\uDE79))?|\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDD25|\uD83E\uDE79))?|[\#\*0-9]\uFE0F?\u20E3|[\u261D\u270C\u270D]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\u270A\u270B](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\u00A9\u00AE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u2328\u23CF\u23ED-\u23EF\u23F1\u23F2\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB\u25FC\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u2692\u2694-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A7\u26B0\u26B1\u26C8\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26E9\u26F0\u26F1\u26F4\u26F7\u26F8\u2702\u2708\u2709\u270C\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u2763\u27A1\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]
```

If you are okay with a few skin tone combinations that do not exist in the test file being matches too, the regex can be compressed to about ~66% (7524 characters)

```
\uD83D(?:\uDC68(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D)?\uDC68|\uD83D(?:(?:[\uDC68\uDC69]\u200D\uD83D)?(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))?|\uDC69(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])|\uD83D(?:(?:\uDC69\u200D\uD83D)?(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83E[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD]))?|(?:\uDD75(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)?|\uDC6F)(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDC6E\uDC70\uDC71\uDC73\uDC77\uDC81\uDC82\uDC86\uDC87\uDE45-\uDE47\uDE4B\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDEA3\uDEB4-\uDEB6](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uDC41(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?)?|\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?)?|\uDE36(?:\u200D\uD83C\uDF2B\uFE0F?)?|\uDC15(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA)?|\uDC3B(?:\u200D\u2744\uFE0F?)?|\uDE2E(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDCA8)?|\uDE35(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDCAB)?|[\uDC42\uDC43\uDC46-\uDC50\uDC66\uDC67\uDC6B-\uDC6D\uDC72\uDC74-\uDC76\uDC78\uDC7C\uDC83\uDC85\uDC8F\uDC91\uDCAA\uDD7A\uDD95\uDD96\uDE4C\uDE4F\uDEC0\uDECC](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD74\uDD90]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uDC08(?:\u200D\u2B1B)?|[\uDC3F\uDCFD\uDD49\uDD4A\uDD6F\uDD70\uDD73\uDD74\uDD76-\uDD79\uDD87\uDD8A-\uDD8D\uDD90\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDDBC\uDDC2-\uDDC4\uDDD1-\uDDD3\uDDDC-\uDDDE\uDDE1\uDDE3\uDDE8\uDDEF\uDDF3\uDDFA\uDECB\uDECD-\uDECF\uDEE0-\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEF0\uDEF3]\uFE0F?|[\uDC00-\uDC07\uDC09-\uDC14\uDC16-\uDC3A\uDC3C-\uDC3E\uDC40\uDC44\uDC45\uDC51-\uDC65\uDC6A\uDC79-\uDC7B\uDC7D-\uDC80\uDC84\uDC88-\uDC8E\uDC90\uDC92-\uDCA9\uDCAB-\uDCFC\uDCFF-\uDD3D\uDD4B-\uDD4E\uDD50-\uDD67\uDDA4\uDDFB-\uDE2D\uDE2F-\uDE34\uDE37-\uDE44\uDE48-\uDE4A\uDE80-\uDEA2\uDEA4-\uDEB3\uDEB7-\uDEBF\uDEC1-\uDEC5\uDED0-\uDED2\uDED5-\uDED7\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDEF4-\uDEFC\uDFE0-\uDFEB])|\uD83E(?:\uDDD1(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]\u200D(?:\u2764\uFE0F?\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDC8B\u200D)?\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92])|[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])|\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|[\uDDAF-\uDDB3\uDDBC\uDDBD])|[\u2695\u2696\u2708]\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF3E\uDF73\uDF7C\uDF84\uDF93\uDFA4\uDFA8\uDFEB\uDFED]|\uD83D[\uDCBB\uDCBC\uDD27\uDD2C\uDE80\uDE92]))?|[\uDD26\uDD35\uDD37-\uDD39\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDCD-\uDDCF\uDDD4\uDDD6-\uDDDD](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDD3C\uDDDE\uDDDF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDD0C\uDD0F\uDD18-\uDD1C\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD30-\uDD34\uDD36\uDD77\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDBB\uDDD2\uDDD3\uDDD5](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDD0D\uDD0E\uDD10-\uDD17\uDD1D\uDD20-\uDD25\uDD27-\uDD2F\uDD3A\uDD3F-\uDD45\uDD47-\uDD76\uDD78\uDD7A-\uDDB4\uDDB7\uDDBA\uDDBC-\uDDCB\uDDD0\uDDE0-\uDDFF\uDE70-\uDE74\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE80-\uDE86\uDE90-\uDEA8\uDEB0-\uDEB6\uDEC0-\uDEC2\uDED0-\uDED6])|\uD83C(?:\uDFF4(?:\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62\uDB40(?:\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67|\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74|\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73)\uDB40\uDC7F|\u200D\u2620\uFE0F?)?|[\uDFC3\uDFC4\uDFCA](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|[\uDFCB\uDFCC](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\uDFF3(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDF08))?|\u200D(?:\u26A7\uFE0F?|\uD83C\uDF08))?|(?:[\uDFCB\uDFCC]\u200D[\u2640\u2642]|[\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDE02\uDE37\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF2C\uDF36\uDF7D\uDF96\uDF97\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E\uDF9F\uDFCD\uDFCE\uDFD4-\uDFDF\uDFF5\uDFF7])\uFE0F?|[\uDF85\uDFC2\uDFC7](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDE6\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF]|\uDDE7\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDE8\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF]|\uDDE9\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF]|\uDDEA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA]|\uDDEB\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7]|\uDDEC\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDED\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA]|\uDDEE\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9]|\uDDEF\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5]|\uDDF0\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDF1\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE]|\uDDF2\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF]|\uDDF3\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF]|\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uDDF5\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uDDF7\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC]|\uDDF8\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF]|\uDDF9\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF]|\uDDFA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDFB\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA]|\uDDFC\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8]|\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uDDFE\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9]|\uDDFF\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC]|[\uDC04\uDCCF\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDE01\uDE1A\uDE2F\uDE32-\uDE36\uDE38-\uDE3A\uDE50\uDE51\uDF00-\uDF20\uDF2D-\uDF35\uDF37-\uDF7C\uDF7E-\uDF84\uDF86-\uDF93\uDFA0-\uDFC1\uDFC5\uDFC6\uDFC8\uDFC9\uDFCB\uDFCC\uDFCF-\uDFD3\uDFE0-\uDFF0\uDFF8-\uDFFF])|\u26F9(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F)(?:\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u200D[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)?|\u2764(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDD25|\uD83E\uDE79))?|\u200D(?:\uD83D\uDD25|\uD83E\uDE79))?|[\#\*0-9]\uFE0F?\u20E3|[\u261D\u270C\u270D]\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\u270A\u270B](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\u00A9\u00AE\u203C\u2049\u2122\u2139\u2194-\u2199\u21A9\u21AA\u2328\u23CF\u23ED-\u23EF\u23F1\u23F2\u23F8-\u23FA\u24C2\u25AA\u25AB\u25B6\u25C0\u25FB\u25FC\u2600-\u2604\u260E\u2611\u2618\u261D\u2620\u2622\u2623\u2626\u262A\u262E\u262F\u2638-\u263A\u2640\u2642\u265F\u2660\u2663\u2665\u2666\u2668\u267B\u267E\u2692\u2694-\u2697\u2699\u269B\u269C\u26A0\u26A7\u26B0\u26B1\u26C8\u26CF\u26D1\u26D3\u26E9\u26F0\u26F1\u26F4\u26F7\u26F8\u2702\u2708\u2709\u270C\u270D\u270F\u2712\u2714\u2716\u271D\u2721\u2733\u2734\u2744\u2747\u2763\u27A1\u2934\u2935\u2B05-\u2B07\u3030\u303D\u3297\u3299]\uFE0F?|[\u231A\u231B\u23E9-\u23EC\u23F0\u23F3\u25FD\u25FE\u2614\u2615\u2648-\u2653\u267F\u2693\u26A1\u26AA\u26AB\u26BD\u26BE\u26C4\u26C5\u26CE\u26D4\u26EA\u26F2\u26F3\u26F5\u26FA\u26FD\u2705\u2728\u274C\u274E\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B50\u2B55]
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/DDjhIn/1) is a demo matching all 4590 listed emoji, plus the 35 added ones.

Answer (score 1):

`Regex.Replace(str, @"[\p{So}\p{Cs}]", string.Empty)`

p{Cs} removes all non BMP characters.

However, p{So} is also required to remove 'other symbols', including certain emojis that are in the BMP.

Answer (score -1):

Regular is not working corectelly.

```
const reg = /(?:(?:\p{RI}\p{RI}|\p{Emoji}(?:\p{Emoji_Modifier}|\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}?|[\u{E0020}-\u{E007E}]+\u{E007F})?(?:\u{200D}\p{Emoji}(?:\p{Emoji_Modifier}|\u{FE0F}\u{20E3}?|[\u{E0020}-\u{E007E}]+\u{E007F})?)*)|[\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}])*/gu;

'♠John♠'.replace(reg, ''); // output "John" - it`s ok
'John 123'.replace(reg, ''); // output John - Numbers is missing, why?
```

Is possible fix regular for keep numbers in string?