# Processing Emojis in SQLite

Tags: sql, encoding, sqlite, emoji

I am hoping to identify which emojis are used most in a text conversation using SQL Lite. I am using DB Browser and the emojis show up like they do in iMessage (see below picture), but I am stumped on how to count them.

I was thinking if there was a way to check and see if a character is not a letter/number/punctuation, then I could count the frequency of all characters that don't fit the prerequisite list. That said, I am unfamiliar with SQLite commands and how I can accomplish that.

Is there a better way to go about this? Let me know if you need more context to answer this question.

[image: Emoji Example]

Comment: Related: [Detecting *all* emojis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46905176/11654)

Comment: Do you have to do this once, or on an ongoing basis?

Comment: @paul not 100% sure what you mean, but just once. I want to run the analysis once on a single file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this with SQLite directly would be to compile SQLite from the source code so you could add support for `regex_replace`.

However, you only plan to do it once, and recompiling SQLite might be a bit overkill.

Instead, you could copy your `text` column into a plain text file, and run the following command:

`sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' temp.txt | sed 's/[[:alnum:].-]//g' | sort -r | uniq -c`

This would turn the following:

`Hello! Are you stuck? 
I saw   in the park!!!!! 
 - all lies.
Easy as 123!`

into:

```
  1 
 11 
  3 
  6 
  1 ?
  7 !
 17
 50
```

Which would hopefully be close enough to get you to your goal. The last two entries are for tabs and spaces.

`sed` is a linux command, so if you are running windows you may want to get a windows version here: https://github.com/mbuilov/sed-windows

Answer (score 0):

Build emojis table, with contains emojis strings in text fields, then try this:

```
SELECT emojis.text, sum(length(replace(message.text, emojis.text, emojis.text || '_')) - length( message.text))
FROM message
INNER JOIN emojis ON message.text LIKE '%' || emojis.text || '%'
GROUP BY emojis.text
```

You can use this method to count occurrences of any text in messages...

Comment: Here is a sqlfiddle validating the answer: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/eccd6/2

Comment: I think the problem here is that "text" field will also have normal text, so I will need to differentiate somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the most efficient example but you could use the group_concat function to merge the text into a single string then use a recursive cte to turn that into a single table of chars. You can filter out all the 'normal' acii chars using the hex function greater than 7F( [see asii table](http://www.asciitable.com/)) you might need to play around with that depending on what your emojis are and whether you have loads of non latin unicode in there. Then it is a simple case of a count if you just want the total or a group by with a count if you want to know what the individual emoji count is.

```
WITH RECURSIVE theChars (
    position
    ,charValue
    )
AS (
    SELECT 2
        ,substr((
                SELECT group_concat(TEXT, '')
                FROM message
                ), 1, 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT position + 1
        ,substr((SELECT group_concat(TEXT, '') FROM message)
            ,position
            ,1)
    FROM theChars LIMIT length((SELECT group_concat(TEXT, '') FROM message))
    )
SELECT charValue,count(*)
FROM theChars
WHERE hex(charValue) > '7F'
group by charValue;
```