# C# - The unicode regular expression to remove emoticons also remove another chars

Tags: c#, regex

I'm using this statement to remove emoticons from a string:

```cs
text = Regex.Replace(text, @"[^\u1F600-\u1F64F]+", "");   //Emoticons
```

Based on the official Unicode page chart, https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1F600.pdf.

But this replace statement not only remove emoticons also removes another characters like "." or "-".

Why is that?

Comment: But mostly of the characters not being removed. Like "A" or "B" or "C"

Comment: The expression in brackets is parsed out as `\u1F60`, `0-\u1F64`, `F`. So it removes everything that is not `\u1F60`, not `F`, and not between character `0` and character `\u1F64`.

Comment: Oh and how it needs to be to remove all between that ranges?

Comment: Use `@"(?:[\0-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFF]|[\uD800-\uD83C\uD83E-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDDFF\uDE50-\uDFFF]|[\uD800-\uDBFF](?![\uDC00-\uDFFF])|(?:[^\uD800-\uDBFF]|^)[\uDC00-\uDFFF])+"`

Comment: Yes, GSerg's link has that convered. Must treat all emoticons as two characters, first of which is the same for all. Must figure out these character pairs for all emoticons.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that not working. it remove all characters

Comment: Yeah, just what `[^\u1F600-\u1F64F]+` does. It removes all but those emojis. The reverse is `@"(?:\uD83D[\uDE00-\uDE4F])+"`

Comment: So, what do you need?

Comment: I need the regular expression that works in c# to remove all the emoticons

Comment: [Here you go](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48148218/3832970).

Comment: Then you should remove the cap character, `^`. When this baby is first character in brackets`[]` it means match everything EXCEPT the stuff that follows inside.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewof course that a more short regular expression will be much better, but this work