# uGUI Text Field, How to Remove "Replacement Characters" (uFFFD aka �)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unicode, emoji, character-replacement

Using the uGUI Text component, I'm getting "replacement characters" aka � and I can't find a way to remove them.

I'm getting a string from the Instagram api which contains unicode characters for both non-alphabet language characters (for Japanese for example) which I need.

However, the unicode characters for the emojis come in as replacement characters aka �. 
I don't require the emojis and they can be stripped out however, I can't find a method to do this.

I'm unable to use TextMeshPro as I'm unable generate a font asset with all the unicode characters need to display the various languages (this could be user error but when I try the process hangs).

I notice these � characters don't appear in the Inspector or console so there must be a way to ignore or remove them.

I'm setting the string like this

```
body.text = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(postData.text);
```

I've tried a number of things that haven't worked including

```cs
    body.text = body.text.Replace('\uFFFD','\'');//doesn't work
    body.text = Regex.Replace(body.text, @"^[\ufffd]", string.Empty);//doesn't work
```

I've also tried breaking up the string as a char array. When I try to print to console I get this error when it hits a replacement character:

```cs
    foreach (char item in postData.text.ToCharArray())
                print(item); //Error: UTF-16 to UTF-8 conversion failed because the input string is invalid
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! 
Thank you.

Unity 2018.4.4, c#

[image: replacement characters can be seen here]

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer!
This post provided a solution: [How do I remove emoji characters from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28023682/how-do-i-remove-emoji-characters-from-a-string)

```
body.text = Regex.Replace(body.text, @"\p{Cs}", "");
```

Comment: I was going to say that Unity still has issues with combining characters (eg, try this string `i̇ ï ị i̤`) but it looks like between 2018.3.7 and 2019.1.7 they fixed that. The only character I can find that doesn't render perfectly is `≠`, looks more like `=​̸`.